# MPMoviePlayerController won't open

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm making an app with a splitviewcontroller and want to play an video.

I have 2 controllers in the split view.
Left (Master) is `VideoMenuTableViewController`
Right (detail) is `VideoViewController`

First i tested if the video works by putting my code in the `viewdidload` of `VideoViewController`.

Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
self.URLForVideoFile = @"http://api.smit-it.info/TEST/VIDEO/two.mov";
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.URLForVideoFile];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];

}
```

This works and the video plays.

Now i try to open the video by touching the title in the `VideoMenuTableViewController`.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *SelectedUrl;
    SelectedUrl = [[[self.dataSource.videos valueForKey:@"URL"] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"URL pressed %@",SelectedUrl);

    VideosViewController *vvc = [[VideosViewController alloc] init];
    vvc.URLForVideoFile = SelectedUrl;

    [vvc PlayMovieFromSelectedUrl];

}
```

Where `PlayMovieFromSelectedUrl` is the same code as in the `viewdidload`
The app crashes and gives the following error.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0xb25c440>
on <VideosViewController: 0xb2565d0> whose view is not in the window
hierarchy!
```

But i don't understand the problem, so i don't know how to fix it.
Please help.

---

UPDATE

By adding 3 lines of code by @PiotrK

```
UIWindow* keyWindow= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[keyWindow addSubview: vvc.view];
[self presentViewController:vvc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

The video plays but when the video is done or dismissed the split view stops responding to everything.

Comment: you can call this method PlayMovieFromSelectedUrl,

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath,
[self PlayMovieFromSelectedUrl] 
otherwise call the method in VideosViewController viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's been some time since I used iOS SDK, but I'll try to help.
The error says it: your VideosViewController is not in the window hierarchy. It means that the window manager doesn't know about the existence of the `vvc` VideosViewController. You have to tell the application that you actually want to display `vvc`. Try this way:

```
...

VideosViewController *vvc = [[VideosViewController alloc] init];
vvc.URLForVideoFile = SelectedUrl;

UIWindow* keyWindow= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[keyWindow addSubview: vvc.view];
[self presentViewController:vvc animated:NO completion:nil];

[vvc PlayMovieFromSelectedUrl];

....
```

Comment: I added your 3 lines of code and it worked. Thanks for the help. I'm now faced with a new problem that the UI won't function/freezes after the video is done.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate  MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp in .h file..or interface in .m file